# Want 40 GB Memory Mapped File but limit is 4 GB? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, memory, virtual-memory

I ran into a problem in .NET where my arrays are limited to the amount of RAM I have and I need arrays which can hold atleast 40 GB of bytes.. I was thinking of a idea of using harddrive as virtual array don't care if its slower.

I was researching this idea and came to `MemoryMappedFile` in VB.net

```
    Dim mmF As MemoryMappedFile
    mmF = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("MemArray", 4294967295)
```

Works to create a 4 GB array but when I try a byte more 4294967296

I get the error
`'The capacity cannot be greater than the size of the system's logical address space.
Parameter name: capacity'`

It's 64-bit system and when I switched from x86 build mode to x64 build mode I can get bigger spaces now but at my desired 40 GB I get a new error `The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.`

**Turned out all I had to do was change the paging file which is defaulted to 800 MB in the screenshot I posted in answer and it works perfectly now!**

So it's capped to 4 GB? is this limit possible to change somewhere in my system? I have over 900 GB of harddrive space available why is 4 GB the limit is there anything I can do or do I have to built a file system completely from primitives to be able to read 40 GB by chunks.

Is there any References or Components that do Big Memory Arrays via Virtual Harddrive space?

Here is my code below

```
Public Function GetRotation(Data As Byte(), rotation As UInteger) As Byte()
    'This works for very big numbers at very fast speeds.
    'This cycle rotates the values without looping array.
    Dim rotationData As New List(Of Byte)

    Dim start As UInteger = Data.Length - rotation Mod Data.Length

    For i = 0 To Data.Length - 1
        rotationData.Add(Data((start + i) Mod (Data.Length)))
    Next

    Return rotationData.ToArray()
End Function

Public Function SortLexicoGraphicallyArrayMappedFile(ByRef data As Byte()) As UInteger()
    Dim OrderedRotations As New List(Of UInteger)
    Dim rotatedData As Byte()
    Dim rotation As UInteger = 0


    Dim mmF As MemoryMappedFile
    'mmF.
    mmF = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("MemArray", 4294967295) 'CLng(data.LongLength * data.LongLength))
    Dim mmVA As MemoryMappedViewAccessor
    mmVA = mmF.CreateViewAccessor(0, data.LongLength * data.LongLength)

    Dim pos As Long = 0

    For rotation = 0 To data.Length - 1
        rotatedData = GetRotation(data, rotation)
        mmVA.WriteArray(Of Byte)(pos, rotatedData, 0, rotatedData.Length)
        pos += rotatedData.LongLength
    Next

    'TODO later sorting them

    Return OrderedRotations.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: Is this a 32-bit system?

Comment: No its 64-bit system and when I switched from x86 build mode to x64 build mode i can get bigger spaces now but at my desired 40 GB I get a new error `The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.`

Comment: If you want a MemoryMappedFile of that size, you may want to switch to a persisten file (a file on disk). [MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.createfromfile). Use multiple random access views.

Comment: There are various limits you'll run into.  Right now you create the MMF without the F and bump into there not being enough space for the M.  Consider to use CreateFromFile() instead.  Next limit you'll run into is that the view of the MMF cannot be larger than 4GB.  Hard limit, even in 64-bit mode.  Having to create multiple views so you access all that virtual memory is not a lot of joy and it starts to get attractive to rethink the data structure.

Comment: @HansPassant The hard limit of 4 GB goes away in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Can you create multiple maps to the same file?

Comment: @user3344003 With `CreateFromFile` you can't have multiple maps using the same file (I set one up as `FileMode.CreateNew` and the next one as  `FileMode.Open`) and I get the error `The process cannot access the file ...because it is being used by another process.`, But without using `CreateFromFile` but instead `CreateOrOpen` which using the microsoft paging file you can map multiple maps to the same file but it serves no purpose you'll just have 2 references to the same thing ya you can make one have a certain size the other have a smaller size that's about it but it will behave the same way

Comment: As already said, when you crete a `MemoryMappedFile`, you then access it using one or more [MemoryMappedViewAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor) (this is the random acces view). You can have as many as you need, the access (read/write) to the underlying data can be concurrent and multi-process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

You need to modify your Virtual memory paging file and use x64 in build mode

[image]